# Selecting Best Location Co-ordinates Based on Accuracy Using GPS?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gps

I want to get best location co-ordinates according to accuracy level but I am using only GPS as provider. So how can I match the accuracy level of different locations?

I meant..do I have to make a separate data structure and store the long, lat and its accuracy and match it with the current fetched accuracy level details?

I only have a single `Location` type var. and a single `LocationManager` type obj.

**Update:** Done. Solved the issue. it was fairly simple :)

How do I go about it?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try the manual? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#BestEstimate

Comment: Can you point me to somewhere where I can have a peek into how the Current location and previous fetched location are getting compared and inside which method? i.e. `onLocationChanged()`? I would prefer a complete version of the sample code..and official manuals just suck at providing "complete sample" :p (no offence Google)

Comment: My link points to the code of a funtion `boolean isBetterLocation(Location location, Location currentBestLocation)`. What else do you need?

Comment: Oh..my bad..din't really looked into the method's body at top :D BTW where should I declare my `LastKnownLocation()` in? Actually, I want to fetch current location based on accuracy of < 10 mtrs. else my app should keep trying to get a lock on a location unless the accuracy is < 10 mtrs. My current code is a bit messed up :| Should I show it to you? :D

Comment: Please, I don't want to see any code ;) You might want to use a `LocationListener` to update your location and call the method I cited from `onLocationChanged(...)`.